# Get contacts by IDs in batch in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a list of IDs which I want to pull the corresponding contacts from Microsoft Graph. I tried filtering with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=Id eq 'my-id-here' or Id eq 'other-id-here'` but it says

> ErrorInvalidProperty The property 'Id' does not support filtering.

I know than I can query by calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/my-id-here` but I want to request multiple at once to minimize round trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use batch processing to execute multiple requests. For each request you need to provide a request id, a http method and a request url. Sample request:

```
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Http Method: POST
Request Body: 

{
      "requests": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "/me/contacts/firstId"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "/me/contacts/secondId"
        }
     ]
}
```

Graph will send a response such as:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                ...
            },
            "body": {
                ...
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                ...
            },
            "body": {
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure, that you check for the id of the request, since requests may not be returned in order, in which you sent them to Graph. The Microsoft documentation on batch processing provides more information: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/json-batching).

Comment: You need to use `dependsOn` and chain these requests to avoid throttling.  Otherwise, Graph will assume you want all N requests executed concurrently, and you'll get throttling errors because there is a limit of 4 concurrent requests per mailbox per application.